# Discord uri generator doesn't work when creating a bot

Tags: windows, oauth-2.0, discord, discord.py, uri

I'm having trouble getting my bot's url generator to work, It's basically saying "Please enter a redirect uri". These nothing on google about that. Can anyone help me fix this?

Here's a screenshot

[image: 1]

Basically it is supposed to give me an invite link for my bot.

Comment: Did you select "bot" on that page?

Comment: Yes, still doesn't work

Comment: Can you send a full screenshot instead of just that one line?

Comment: here's [Screenshot](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1048285498273181727/1058080367938113576/image.png?width=1440&height=662)

Comment: That's the least useful part, there's something higher up as well where you have to select the right option (called "scopes"). All the way at the top of that page.

Comment: I tired lol I know how to create a bot application It's Just it stopped working for some reason [screenshot](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1048285498273181727/1058403037640663121/image.png?width=1071&height=585)

Comment: If you only selected `bot` there then there's only one possible thing. Did you select `requires OAuth2 code grant` on the **bot** page? Select `Bot` in the left sidepanel (under `OAuth2`), and at the top of the page under `Authorization Flow` make sure `REQUIRES OAUTH2 CODE GRANT` is disabled.

Comment: I don't have this option in my developer portal

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of what you _do_ have?

Comment: I figured it out why I wasn't getting the invite link, as you stated above I enabled  "requires OAuth2 code grant" by accident. I'm sorry for wasting your time but thanks again for explaining

Comment: I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 4):

Select `Bot` in the left sidepanel (under `OAuth2`), and at the top of the page under `Authorization Flow` make sure `REQUIRES OAUTH2 CODE GRANT` is disabled.

Next, on the `OAuth2` page, make sure you don't have any extra scopes other than `bot` selected.